# How to get Rails 4 ActionController::Live streaming working with Thin and Ruby 2? And how do Thin and Puma scale with live streaming?

Tags: streaming, thin, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, puma

I get it working with Puma, but with Thin I don't get any stream output and I have to kill the server to stop it. I'm testing using tenderlove's initial example outputing the current time:

http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html

A more general question to me is, is this type of streaming practical in an app with any significant traffic? I imagine there can be easily hunderts if not thousands of users connected to a stream at once in such app. How would Puma scale here? I read that Puma uses 1 thread per connection. Is that efficient? And what about Thin? Will all connections be in the same thread? Will that be more efficient?

Another issue I have is that even with Puma I only get one connection working locally. When I  curl from a second terminal I don't get any output there...  Anybody know why?

Comment: Thin doesn't work for me neither with rails 4 streaming. Does it support streaming at all?? Puma runs fine :)

Answer (score 1):

If you change your development.rb inside environments:

**/config/environments/development.rb**

```
config.cache_classes = true

config.eager_load = true
```

You will be able to get more than one connection with puma localy! The downside is that you have to restart everytime you want to see any changes you've made.